# What is wrong with my "digit finder" in python?

Tags: python

I am learning python through the Project Euler problems.  For  [problem 40](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=40)  I wrote this code:

```
import math
i = 1
counter = 0
while counter <= 1000000:
    MMM = int(math.log(i, 10)) + 1
    counter = counter + MMM
    V = math.log(i, 10)
    print(i, counter, MMM, V)
    i += 1
```

It is supposed to return the number containing the Nth digit.  Basically, this is supposed to keep track of what would happen if I concatenated the integers from 1 through whatever into another number.  The goal is to determine what a specific digit is.  This code works below a certain threshold, however, by the time it gets to the millionth digit it is off by one.  What am I missing here?  I have seen other implementations that save time, but I am more interested in why the count becomes wrong at some point

Edit:

replacing

```
MMM = int(math.log(i, 10)) + 1
```

with

```
MMM = len(str(i))
```

works like a champ!

Although it would be nice to have an all numeric solution, It'll have to wait until I can trust log functions in Python.

Comment: Big, big, big hint: don't think about this as a fractional number, think about it as a string.

Comment: I figured out pretty quick that it would have to be done using strings, but after compiling a string long enough to contain 1000000 digits I figured that there should be a way to "count" which appended number has which digit and index it in such a way as to know which digits were actually being represented by the number being appended.  The code I wrote actually does this, the value of counter gives the digit number of the last digit in the number being appended.  However, somewhere there is a breakdown and the counter is off by one.  I want to know why and when this happens.

Comment: Just to clarify what is going on behind my math.  The integer part of the common log of any number is the number of digits minus one. (As far as I know...)  So if I add one to the common log of successive numbers and keep track of these values buy keeping a running total, the Nth digit should be contained by the number that is appended when the total counter is greater than N for example:
when the number 366 is appended there are 987 digits, so it contains the 988th 989th and 990th digits.

Comment: log is probably too heavy-weight and imprecise for keeping track of how many digits numbers have, when looped over sequentially. There are probably more precise ways using only integer arithmetics: (modulus,) addition and multiplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the problem line

```
MMM = int(math.log(i, 10)) + 1
```

Some examples

```
>>> int(math.log(1000000, 10)) + 1
6
>>> int(math.log(1000001, 10)) + 1
7
```

Whereas I suspect you really wanted

```
>>> len(str(1000000))
7
>>> len(str(1000001))
7
```

**Edit** Actually (as you suggested!) math.log10 seems to be the best solution and more in line with what you wrote originally

```
>>> int(math.log10(10000000))
7
>>> int(math.log10(10000001))
7
>>> int(math.log10(10**1000))
1000
>>> int(math.log10(10**10000))
10000
>>> int(math.log10(10**100000))
100000
```

`math.log10` must keep the accuracy better than `math.log(x, 10)`

Comment: in addition to what I commented on below, I was not aware that the len() function worked in this way on strings.  I was under the impression that it would only count elements ie len(str(100000)) would be 1 and not 6.  I'll keep that in mind from now on.

Comment: it indeed does only count elements, but strings are really lists of characters. to get a result of 1, you would have to count a list of a string: len([str(100000)])

Answer (score 4):

Floating point error somewhere along the way? It might be possible that at some point `math.log` is returning something that's barely less than (or greater, depending on the direction of your off-by-1 result) an integer boundary and thus `int()` is truncating it to the wrong value. Floating-point numbers are not precise for numbers which can't be represented using a certain number of binary digits.

Comment: That seems reasonable.  Since the values of math.log will be closer and closer to integer values as the number of digits gets larger.  In other words, log(999999) has a "more" nines in its decimal part than log(99).  Is there a way to combat this or am I at the mercy of the nature of floating points no matter what with this method?

Comment: @Jim: I think you're right, and using `log` subjects you to the floating-point inaccuracy in corner cases. Certainly a unique way of solving, however.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is one of precision of floating point numbers which is not amazing. I gets fuzzier and fuzzier as the number of digits increase. This is the basic nature of floating point numbers, when you are doing this kind of math you need to be aware what precision you require.

The standard library module [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) allows you fine grained control of the precision of decimal values. Since this module is not hardware bases allows the user alter the precision of floating point number (the default is 28 places). You create decimal numbers like below:

```
 import decimal
 x = decimal.Decimal(1000000)
 x.log10()
```

You can alter the precision you require like this: `decimal.getcontext().prec = 8`